# Setting custom span on TextView with style applied in XML

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

I have a TextView that uses an app wide style set in XML that I would like to keep in the XML definition. Now if I find a special string in a message I want to set on the TextView I would like to underline it. Now this is pretty simple using the `UnderlineSpan` class and setting the stand and end. The problem is when I have a style set in XML the span is completely ignored, if I remove the style the underline is correct. How can I have a style applied in XML and be allowed to apply custom spans?

**EDIT:**

My style in the styles.xml file is this:

```
<style name="Heading3Style">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black_red</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_heading_1</item>
    <item name="font">ROCKWELL_STD_BOLD</item>
</style>
```

The font attribute is a custom attribute that is pulled by a class extending TextView to load a custom font from XML. My layout file has this definition:

```
<com.mypackage.views.font.FontTextView
    android:id="@+id/titleView"
    style="@style/Heading3Style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin" />
```

This is the code where I am trying to apply a span to the text. For simplicity I just used the `UnderLine` span on the entire string to test but this doesn't work. Once I have the `Spannable` working I will replace this with a custom `Spannable` to make changes to only parts of the string.

```
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(modifierGroup.getName());
spannable.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, modifierGroup.getName().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
titleView.setText(spannable);
```

This does nothing to the string, it just displays it like normal with the `Heading3Style` applied but no underline. If I remove the `style="@style/Heading3Style` from the XML definition everything works as expected.

Comment: "The problem is when I have a style set in XML the span is completely ignored" -- huh? We really need a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to understand what your exact issue is.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've updated the question with an example, hope that helps a bit.

Comment: What is `font`? There is nothing in Android for setting a font via a style. Are you using some third-party library? If so, then your third-party library is probably the source of your interference.

Comment: It's not a third party it's my own custom view that just has a custom namespace attribute to load a custom font from the assets directory. All that is doing is taking that Enum value and loading a specific TypeFace and setting it using setTypeface on the TextView.

Comment: I suggest you roll back to a plain `TextView` and no style. Confirm your span works. Then add an empty style. Confirm your span works. Add in a single attribute to the style. Confirm your span works. Repeat until all attributes are back in (but you are still using an ordinary `TextView`). See if your span works. Then add back in the custom view. Use that to determine *specifically* where things are breaking down. Right now, you have a fair number of moving parts.

Comment: Alright, will do. Thanks for the help. I'll post back once I hopefully figure this one out.